# Java: non-distributed event-processing

Tags: java, spring, event-handling, akka

My application logic should be based on event processing. Its not that hard to implement corresponding producer-consumer patterns and event classes. But first I would like to ensure this was not implemented before.

I would like to specify that I am talking about non-distributed event-processing. I.e. I dont need to serialize my events and send them to some other JVMs.

Which options do I have?

1. I use Spring. In Spring there is event-handling support already present. Is Spring event-processing robust enough? What are the limitations?
2. I can use Akka. Good, but Akka is mainly for distributed systems. Is it worth to use it for single JVM application?
3. I can implement this by myself. Not a big deal, but I always prefer to consult stackoverflow before reinventing the wheel.

?

Comment: I think your question is way too broad; but a few comments: you are not distributed today, but maybe tomorrow? So, that would be an argument to still consider Akka. On the other hand, one should never forgot about YAGNI, too (you aint gonna need it). But then: you think that you can no-big-deal implement robust event processing, but you dont trust some advanced framework like spring to do that?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Akka but AFAIK it's not mainly addressing distributed systems. You can also use it to build concurrent applications based on message passing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [Spring Integration](http://projects.spring.io/spring-integration/). It has the kind if event processing you're talking about along with a myrid of inputs/outputs, plus the ability to route, transform (with arbitrary Java), and complex error handling. I've used it before for a REST service that was fronting Kafka and we were very happy with it.